# Add a number to the front of a number row python

Tags: python, rows

In python there is the .append function to add a number to the back of a row:

```
coordinate_row.append(coordinate)
```

However, i would like to add a number to the front of a row. like this:

```
[1,2,3]
```

add 4

```
[4,1,2,3]
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the `+` operator for this

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> l = [4] + l
>>> l
[4, 1, 2, 3]
```

Or in your case

```
coordinate_row = list(coordinate) + coordinate_row
```

As a function

```
def front_append(l, item):
    return [item] + l

>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> l = front_append(l, 4)
>>> l
[4, 1, 2, 3]
```

Alternatively, you can use the `list` method `insert` with position `0`

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> l.insert(0, 4)
>>> l
[4, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I would like to make a function to do this, how would that work?

Comment: @Pieter Writing a function is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
coordinate_row = [1, 2, 3]
coordinate = [4]
coordinate_row = coordinate + coordinate_row
print coordinate_row  # output:  [4, 1, 2, 3]
```